# how to show currently logged user data in the gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2017

I am trying to get a datagrid view to only show the details of a logged in user instead of all details from every user.
They way i have this set up so far is once a user logs in the login value is passed to the next page to the "Username_Alerts_lbl".

My Idea of how to do this is once the login value is passed to the 
"Username_Alerts_lbl" you can somehow do a check against the datagridview to display only the logged in users details.

The first Column in the datagrid is where the users login details are displayed and ive tried to compare against but unsure of it.

i am doing this in the page load so once the user opens up the page they can only see their details.

The error i get is at the f (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == **+Username_Alerts_lbl.Text**)  and im unsure how to do this.

```
     public string conString = "StringConnection";

    private void Alerts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'attendanceAppSignInOutDataSet.Sign_In_Out_Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.sign_In_Out_TableTableAdapter.Fill(this.attendanceAppSignInOutDataSet.Sign_In_Out_Table);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT eb_number From User_Table WHERE eb_number='" + Username_Alerts_lbl.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == +Username_Alerts_lbl.Text)
            sda.Fill(dt);
            {

            }

        }
```

Comment: It will help attract more answers to a question if you tag the correct programming language. This is C#, not C.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution to this

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT eb_number, Sign_In, Sign_out, Date FROM sign_In_Out_Table WHERE eb_number='" + Username_Alerts_lbl.Text + "'", con);
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("eb_number", Username_Alerts_lbl.Text);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            {

            }

        }
```